# Can one use, or how to avoid using, a colon (":") as the start of a path to an sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, qgis

I am creating a plugin for QGIS ([QGIS Plugin Builder](https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder)). The relative paths to the plugin directory need to start with a colon. The icon for example is loaded like this:

```
icon_path = ':/plugins/into_sqlite/icon.png'
```

When I try to do the same for the sqlite database the database fails to load:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(":/plugins/PLUGINNAME/database.sqlite")
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

But when I try the same giving the absolute path it works:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("/home/USERNAME/.qgis/python/plugins/PLUGINNAME/database.sqlite")
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I think that the problem is that the path starts with a colon and sqlite uses the colon as a special character to for example load a database in memore:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
```

But I need to use realtive paths. How can I supply the path and escape the colon or start the path without the colon?

Answer (score 0):

I now went around the problem by using this code:

```
path = abspath(":/plugins/PLUGINNAME/")
path_abs = path.replace(":", ".qgis2/python")
path_db = join(path_abs, "db.sqlite")
connection = sqlite3.connect(path_db)
```

The variables have these values:

```
path = "/home/USERNAME/:/plugins/PLUGINNAME"
path_abs = "/home/USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins/PLUGINNAME"
path_db = "/home/USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins/PLUGINNAME/db.sqlite"
```

#### Another suggestion:

On IRC the suggestion was:

```
curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.path_db = os.path.join(curr_path, 'db.sqlite')
```